# Keep scroll position of a DIV after a FORM submit using session var or CSS

Tags: html, css, session-variables

I have a DIV in a page that has a vertical scroll.
Inside that DIV I have a lot of rows that contain a FORM with a submit button.

```
<div>
<form>text1 <input type=submit></form><BR />
<form>text2 <input type=submit></form><BR />
<form>text3 <input type=submit></form><BR />
[...]
<form>text99 <input type=submit></form><BR />
</div>
```

What I want is that after one clicks one of that submit buttons the div should jump to the scroll position it was before. Right now it jumps to position 1 what is very inconvenient. The page is not using JavaScript at all.

Is there a way to do it with CSS or HTML/CSS?

or maybe using session variables(NOT cookies)?

Comment: What is the behavior of the form? Does it reload the page? If so, you could capture the click on the submit button, append the current position to the URL as a query parameter or hash, and then execute the request as you normally would. Then, on each page load, set the position based on the URL parameter / hash.

Comment: yes it reloads the page. can you make a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been try'n'erroring some hours.

The solution is very simple, you need no jQuery and no Java, just plain HTML

```
<div>
    <form id="link1" action="#link1" >text1 <input type=submit></form><BR />
    <form id="link2" action="#link2" >text2 <input type=submit></form><BR />
    <form id="link3" action="#link3" >text3 <input type=submit></form><BR />
     [...]
    <form id="link99" action="#link99" >text99 <input type=submit></form><BR />
</div>
```

It's going to jump to the id called like the form action link, regardless in what tag the id is. Even this is working:

```
<div>
    <form action="#link1" >text1 <input id="link1" type=submit></form><BR />
    <form action="#link2" >text2 <input id="link2" type=submit></form><BR />
    <form action="#link3" >text3 <input id="link3" type=submit></form><BR />
    [...]
    <form action="#link99" >text99 <input id="link99" type=submit></form><BR />
</div>
```

Have fun guys.